# How to set an Alarm in latest iOS using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, eventkit

In iOS 8, Event Kit was released along with the ability to use EKAlarm.

More info here: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_iOS_8_Event_Kit_and_Swift_to_Create_Date_and_Location_Based_Reminders

1. Has anyone tried using this to setup Alarms in iOS using this?
2. Because alarms are notoriously difficult to work with in iOS in terms of launching an app from background mode, I was hoping to use EKAlarm. Would EKAlarm be a better option than setting up Local Notifications?
3. As of iOS 9 or 10, is there a better way to setup alarms other than having the app stay in foreground the whole time?

Most posts on SO suggest to use UILocalNotification, however, in my situation, I need additional things to happen in my app aside from a system alert (notification) the user receives. Additionally, it seems that UILocalNotification has a maximum of 30 seconds to play a sound. Obviously, an alarm needs more, and provide the ability to snooze, and other options provided within App.

4. Having said that, is UILocalNotification really the best option here?